# Windows commandline help

Tags: windows, command-line

I want to copy the folder "C:\documents and settings\hp\my documents"  to D:\ through the Windows cmd console.  How can i do this?

Comment: Do you actually mean DOS? Or do you mean from the Windows command line (which is not DOS, but looks similar)?

Comment: Well, the 'documents and settings' is a clue.

Answer (score 2):

```
xcopy /e "C:\Documents and Settings\hp\My Documents" D:\
```